# Cannot retrieve EstimatedCharges using AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to fetch **EstimatedCharges** data using the AWS API.  I am using the PHP library they provide.  Everything works fine except that no datapoints are returned.  Some observations:

- If I change the StartTime and EndTime parameters so it would result in more than 1,440 datapoints, the call fails with a code 400 because too many datapoints would be returned.  So this leads to conclude I am making the proper call.
- I can successfully pull other metrics such as **CPUUtilizationRate** and **CPUCreditBalance**.  It is only **EstimatedCharges** that is not working.
- I can use the AWS CLI to successfully pull data using the same key and secret.

My code:

```
<?php


date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

require_once('../sdk.class.php');
require '../aws-autoloader.php';


$cw = Aws\CloudWatch\CloudWatchClient::factory(array(
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-08-01',
    'credentials' => array(
    'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'yyyyyyyyyyy'


    )
));

  $count = $cw->getMetricStatistics(array(


    'MetricName'  => 'EstimatedCharges',
    'Statistics' => array('Maximum'),
    'Unit' => 'Count',                  
    'Namespace' => 'AWS/Billing',    

    'StartTime' => '03/09/2017',
    'EndTime' => '03/13/2017',
    'Period' => 300,


    'Dimensions' => array(
         array('Name' => 'Currency', 'Value' => 'USD')
    ),        

));

echo $count;
```